# Pass variable to nested shortcode

Tags: plugins, shortcode

I'm setting up a plugin with a nested shortcode, i.e.

```
[ct_training_group]
    [ct_training]
[/ct_training_group]
```

Here's the catch: I use the `[ct_training]` code outside of the parent as well as within it, and want to output something slightly different in each case. When it is inside a group, I need to omit the `<ul>` and `</ul>` that I would wrap the `[ct_training]` shortcode in when it is called on its own.

I figure the easiest way to do this would be to pass a variable from the parent to the child. Is there any graceful way to do this where I wouldn't need to mess with globals or such?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you just pass the content of `ct_training_group` to another call of `do_shortcode()`? You can't pass extra parameters to it, so if you don't want to use global state variables, you could always replace the current shortcode handler for `ct_training` with one that doesn't add the extra `<ul>`. It seems there is no cache for the handlers, so there will not be a performance penalty.

```
add_shortcode('ct_training', 'ct_training_full');
function ct_training_full($attr, $content)
{
    return '<ul>' . ct_training_item($attr, $content) . '</ul>';
}

function ct_training_item($attr, $content)
{
    return '<li>CT Training</li>';
}

add_shortcode('ct_training_group', 'ct_training_group_handler');
function ct_training_group_handler($attr, $content)
{
    $output = '<h3>CT Training group</h3>';
    $output .= '<ul>';
    // Redefine the sub-code
    add_shortcode('ct_training', 'ct_training_item');
    $output .= do_shortcode($content);
    // Reset the sub-code
    add_shortcode('ct_training', 'ct_training_full');
    $output .= '</ul>';
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Nice, clean idea.